# C# user control's background image

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a custom control that I'm inheriting from Control. I need to display an icon so I'm using the available properties (BackgroundImage and BackgroundImageLayout).

I select an image and set the layout to None. However, I don#t want that the image is draw in the top-left corner of the control, but in another location that I specify.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this inside your `OnPaint()`;

```
Image myBackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("xyz.jpg");

 e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBackgroundImage, myX, myY, new Rectangle(0, 0, myBackgroundImage.Width, myBackgroundImage.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

You're telling the Graphics object to draw your image at the specific location of myX and myY. The rectangle is the portion of the image to draw, in this case the whole image.

Comment: I tried that. The above code draws the image correctly at the specified location. However, because the layout is 'None', the control automatically draws the image again at (0, 0). So I finish with 2 images.

Comment: Don't use the BackgroundImage and BackgroundImageLayout properties, just this code inside OnPaint()

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono `myBackgroundImage` in the code was referring to a new image, not the BackgroundImage property.

Comment: Yes the only way is to add a new property and not use BackgroundImage.